# Problema con Handlebars < app.engine(".hbs", (0, _expressHandlebars["default"])({ >

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, handlebars

Estoy realizando un curso de un projecto con Handlebars del cual he seguido todo al pie de la letra pero al momento de configurar el Handlebars me lanza un error que no lo comprendo y ya he intentado de todo y no se que es.}

**Error**

```
app.engine(".hbs", (0, _expressHandlebars["default"])({

TypeError: (0 , _expressHandlebars.default) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Sitio uno\MongoDB-Intermediate\src\/app.js:18:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Module._compile (D:\Sitio uno\MongoDB-Intermediate\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (D:\Sitio uno\MongoDB-Intermediate\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Sitio uno\MongoDB-Intermediate\src\/index.js:1:1)
```

**Configuración de Handlebars**

```
import express from "express";
import exphbs from "express-handlebars";
import path from "path";

//Ubicacion de la carpeta views
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

console.log(app.get('views'))

//Motor de plantilla
app.engine(
  ".hbs",
  exphbs({
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
    defaulLayout: "main",
    extname: ".hbs",
  })
);

app.set("view engine", ".hbs");
```

**Package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-handlebars": "^6.0.1",
"mongoose": "^6.0.13",
"morgan": "^1.10.0"
```

}

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir cómo estás importando `handlebars`?

Comment: Tiene pinta de ser la llamada a handleBars. Si pudieras aportarlo a la pregunta nos sería de utilidad.

Comment: Acabo de modificar agregando como se importa Handlebars y el Package.json

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [TypeError: exphbs is not a function](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/497722/typeerror-exphbs-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta a mi me funciono https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/497728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me eh topado con el mismo problema...checando mi código observe esto
[image: check del problema]

y el directorio de mi proyecto esta de esta forma

[image: Directorio del proyecto]

en conclusión encontré que no se podía encontrar el archivo ya que la ruta al archivo estaba mal, ruta mal: 'C:\Users\b_e_t\Desktop**MyNotes\views\layouts\main.hbs**'
ruta correcta:
'C:\Users\b_e_t\Desktop**MyNotes\src\views\layouts\main.hbs**'
lo solucione configurando de esta manera:

```
const hbs = create({
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: path.join("src/views", "layouts"),
    defaultLayout:'main'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Un resultado. que he encontrado.

```
import express from "express";
import {create} from "express-handlebars";

import indexRoutes from "./routes/index.routes";
import path from "path";

const app = express();

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

const exphbs = create({
  extname: '.hbs',
  layoutsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
  partialsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "partials"),
  defaultLayout:'main'
});

app.engine(".hbs", exphbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

app.use(indexRoutes);

export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import express from "express";
import { create } from "express-handlebars";
import indexRoutes from "./routes/index.routes";
import path from "path";

const app = express();

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

//Motor de plantillla engine

const exphbs = create({
  extname: '.hbs',
  layoutsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
  defaultLayout:'main'
});

app.engine(".hbs", exphbs.engine);
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");

// Routes
app.use(indexRoutes);

export default app;
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Gracias por tu aporte, pero deberias leerte el apartado de la ayuda que explica [answer] para aprender a realizar buenas respuestas. En tu caso has puesto solo código sin ninguna explicación de los cambios que has realizado ni el porque de los mismos, lo cual ayudaria a entender a los demás el porque tu solución es válida para esta pregunta. Gracias. Tambien es aconsejable que realices el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Puedes [edit] tu respuesta y agregar lo que falta.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema fue que la documentación de handelbars cambio. Me sirvió sustituir el código por:

```
    import path from "path";
    import express from "express";
    import indexRoutes from "./routes/index";
    import { create } from "express-handlebars";
    
    const app = express();
    
    // settings
    app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
    app.engine(
      ".hbs",
      create({
        layoutsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "layouts"),
        partialsDir: path.join(app.get("views"), "partials"),
        defaulLayout: "main",
        extname: ".hbs",
      }).engine
    );
    app.set("view engine", ".hbs");
    
    app.use(indexRoutes);
    
    export default app;
```

Comment: Marca tu respuesta como la mejor respuesta para que si alguien se encuentra con tu problema sepa resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion que he encontrado es remplazar esta linea de codigo:

const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");

app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({defaultLayout:"main"}));

Por este codigo:

app.engine("handlebars", exphbs.engine({ defaultLayout: "main" }));

Espero ayude.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.