# TypeError: exphbs is not a function

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, handlebars.js

Tengo este error pero no se pór que me lo muestra
estoy ejecuntado una aplicaciones node js asi que empecé con los setings y todo normal hasta este punto que me dice exphbs no es una función

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const session = require('express-session');
let exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'Partials'),
    extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

y me da este error [image: TypeError: exphbs is not a function]
Agradecería cualquier ayuda

Comment: No es `app.set('.hbs', exphbs({.. .})`. Cambia esa línea por: `app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({...})` y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Has probado esta solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959820/typeerror-exphbs-is-not-a-function

Comment: Deberias probar `exphbs.engine({..` en vez de `exphbs({..`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás importando el módulo de express-handlebars así:

```
let exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
```

Pero [en la documentación](https://github.com/express-handlebars/express-handlebars) se está usando así:

```javascript
import express from 'express';
import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', engine());
```

Es decir, la llamada require('express-handlebars'); devuelve un objeto que tiene un atributo llamado engine, que es la función que estás buscando. Es posible que esto sea un cambio reciente en el comportamiento, puesto que se está portando todo el módulo en Typescript. Si es así, es posible que tengas ejemplos/documentación desactualizados.

Answer (score 4):

Debido a cambios no tan recientes en la libreria express-handlebars el default export cambió, y ya no es la funcion engine, por lo que con cambiar la linea de codigo de
exphbs(... a algo como exphbs.engine(...
soluciona el problema

Snippet con la solución actualizada a la fecha de hoy:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const session = require('express-session');
let exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

//settings
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('.hbs', exphbs.engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'Partials'),
    extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Answer (score 0):

Me estaba pasando y no anduvo nada de esto, pero encontré esta solución:

Cambiar el import de Handlebars

`import { engine } from 'express-handlebars';`

Luego el resto queda así:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    defaultLayout: 'main',
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualizando una nueva solución encontré dos opciones para la versión de node.js v18.16.1:

**Primer Metodo:**

Para ello, basta con actualizar **.enigne**

Cámbialo de esto:

```javascript
let exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

app.set('.hbs', exphbs.engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'Partials'),
    extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

A:

```javascript
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');

app.engine('handlebars', engine({
        defaultLayout: 'main',
        extname: '.hbs',
        layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
        defaultLayout: 'main',
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

Buena Suerte para los nuevos que se han topado con este error.

Answer (score 0):

Para la versión de node.js v18.18.2:

**Cambiar el import así:**

*import { engine } from "express-handlebars";*

**y lo demás..**

```js
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    defaultLayout: 'main',
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.set("view engine", ".hbs");
```